# Automatic Variable and Shadowed the Memory, Scope, In C language

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scope, memory-address

I have a piece of code that does something as simple as this.

```
static Log_t* point2logEntry = NULL;

void function1(void)
{
....
point2logEntry->Member1 = 1;
point2logEntry->Member2 = Member1 + 1; //Member2 will be equal to 2
point2logEntry->Member3 = Member1 + 2; //Member2 will be equal to 3
...
}
```

Now `points2logEntry` has address of some data.

```
void Function2(void)
{
Log_t* points2Log;
function1();
points2log->Member1 = 4;
points2log->Member2 = 5;
points2log->Member3 = 6;

point2logEntry = points2log;
/* At this point, the compiler/debugger window shows the memory address of the 2 pointers are one and the same. Shadowed and the watch window shows. 
 point2logEntry->Member1  //Member2 will be equal to 4
 point2logEntry->Member2  //Member2 will be equal to 5
 point2logEntry->Member3  //Member2 will be equal to 6
*/    
}
```

Now `point2logEntry = points2log;` This is set in `Function2` and `Function2` makes a call to `Function1`.

In `Function3` below

```
void Function3(void)
{
...
Function2(); //see Question1 below

}
```

what i see in watch window is the address of `points2log` is mirrored/shadowed to `point2logEntry`.

Question1) Since `points2log` in `function2` was an automatic variable and but its address was shadowed to a static scoped pointer `point2logEntry`. After `function2` is executed, will the members of the `point2logEntry` still have the latest data in it?

Question2)When and why would you do something like this (mirror memory address)? Is there any benefit to do this or is it programmer preference.

My Understanding: You can essentially use `points2logEntry` for all your `function2` needs (because of static lifetime) but the programmer dude in this case used in this fashion. In fact when the `function2` is "pop" out from stack the automatic variable `Log_t* points2Log;` disappears and data is no longer available. BUT the address is passed to the `point2logEntry` and after the scope of `function2` expires the address is lost forever.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: The problem that the automatic variable will disappear but how does the data still remains in the static variable. This would mean that the address still has the data even after the automatic variable disappears? I am a little confused by the way its used.

Comment: If you call function1 first, point2logEntry is NULL. If you call Functions2 points2log is undefined. What was your question?

Comment: C is not high level where you have garbage collector to clean mess for you. You have to do it on your own.

Comment: This really depends on what is in the `...` . Please post real code

Comment: Post your full code. And what is your exact question ?

Comment: Hint: What's the lifetime of `points2Log`?